# Why is average outputting inf?

Tags: c, casting

This is not all of my code but this is the setup I have. When I tried to compute average I'm getting `inf` as an answer. Instead I should be getting a decimal. Am I casting it wrong? What am I doing wrong?

```
typedef struct hash_table_ {
  data_el **order;
  int *number_next_calls;
  int *number_buckets;
  int *buckets_size;
  int *worst;
  int *total;
  float *average;
  int (*hash_func)(char *);
  int (*comp_func)(void*, void*);
  data_el **buckets_array;
} hash_table, *Phash_table;

...
Phash_table table;
...

int temp_total,temp_buckets_size;
temp_total = *table->total;
temp_buckets_size = *table->buckets_size;
*(table->average) = (float)temp_total/(float)temp_buckets_size;
printf("%f\n",*(table->average));
```

Comment: You need to replace the pointers for things like `worst`, `total`, `number_buckets`, `number_next_calls` with simple values (`buckets_size` is an allocated array of integers).  I gave you a pretty big hint about that in an answer to [another question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467348/why-is-this-passing-the-if-statement) with this data structure showing up.

Comment: Surely even in C you cannot have need with *that* many pointers!

Comment: What is the value of temp_buckets_size?

Comment: temp_buckets_size is total number of buckets.

Comment: The easiest way to get an infinite average is to divide by zero.

Comment: Run your program through valgrind, just for giggles. $100 says that every part of it is incorrect in one way or another.

Comment: There's a reason why us C++ coders don't like pointers, this is a very good example of this reason!

Comment: @LearningC: But what is the actual *number* stored in `temp_buckets_size`?

Answer (score 1):

If you divide by zero, you will either get a floating point exception (and core dump if those are enabled) or you'll get an infinity.

Since you're printing `Inf`, it seems you are being molly-coddled by your system; the core dump is better, in ,y jaundiced and archaic opinion.

Comment: For systems that conform to IEEE 754, division by zero is well-defined and cannot produce a signal (unless you've enabled trapping exceptions). The result is +- infinity if the numerator is nonzero, and NAN if the numerator and denominator are both 0.

Comment: The old fashioned, pre-standard systems where divide by zero gives an exception are better then!  Standardized molly-coddling is bad for the health of novice programmers.

Comment: It's not "molly-coddling" whatever that term is supposed to mean. It's doing what anyone performing serious numerical computing expects. Integer division by zero does result in UB (usually SIGFPE), but for floating point, division by zero is not an error because zero is not necessarily arrived at as an exact zero. In the case where zero was the result of rounding a very small but nonzero value, the correct result of division by zero is a very large value (much larger than the largest representable finite value), for which infinity is the best approximation.

Comment: [Molly-coddle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mollycoddle): _To be overprotective and indulgent toward. See Synonyms at pamper._  Seems like exactly the right term to me.  Also, given the we're dividing what were two integers, there's no question of a very small but non-zero value; either it was zero or it was not.

Comment: In integer arithmetic, if you're dividing by zero, you're definitely doing something wrong. There's no reasonable result the operation could give, and the zero is exact, so you have an error in your program logic. In floating point, on the other hand, there *is* a reasonable result, and it was chosen this way not to help incompetent coders with buggy code (actually IMO it makes things much harder for them), but by experts in numerical computing who, as far as I know, pretty much unanimously agreed on the behavior for division by zero. The controversial thing was gradual underflow...